# Удалить часть строки через preg_replace

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Есть строка:

```
$str ='http://site.ru/view?page=1&cat=2';
```

Нужно удалить `?page=1`, только вместо цифры 1 может быть другое число. Пробовал так, не вышло:

```
$str = preg_replace("?page=[0-9]",'',$str);
```

Comment: Рекомендую сперва прочитать как использовать регулярные выражения, их базовый синтаксис, прежде чем пытаться их применять

Comment: @Rufex, после такого удаление url будет кривой. Имею в виду параметры.

Comment: @Visman, это понятно, главное регулярка чтобы работала

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ответ на ваш вопрос

```
$str = preg_replace('/\?page=[0-9]+/','',$str);
```

Для того чтобы убрать параметр из урл нужна другая регулярка

```
$str = preg_replace('/page=[0-9]+&?/','',$str);
```

Для тестирования регулярок удобно пользоваться онлайн сервисами, например http://regexr.com/

Comment: Не будет работать для 10 страницы и выше :Р

Comment: поправил регулярку

Comment: А еще гляньте на мой комментарий к самому вопросу.

Comment: @Visman, я ответил на вопрос. Автор вопроса тоже видел комментарий, думаю поймет как изменять регулярку под свои нужды

Comment: @MarselArduanov, автор вопроса еще не видел моего комментария, так как был на сайте 18 мин назад.

Answer (score 3):

Мой вариант.

```
$str = preg_replace('/((\?(?!.*&))*page=\d+&*)/', '', $str);
```

Удаляет знак вопроса перед `page=N`, если за ними не следует амперсанд.

Если амперсанд следует за `page=N`, то знак вопроса остается, а амперсанд удаляется.

Для

```
http://site.ru/view?page=1&cat=2
http://site.ru/view?page=1
```

получаем

```
http://site.ru/view?cat=2 
http://site.ru/view
```

Пример работы https://regex101.com/r/fO4uO3/1

**UPD**

Более точное регулярное выражение https://regex101.com/r/fO4uO3/2

```
$str = preg_replace('/(((\?|&)(?!.*&))*(?<=\?|&)page=\d+&*)/i', '', $str);
```

Для

```
http://site.ru/view?cat=2&page=1
http://site.ru/view?page=1
http://site.ru/view?page=1&cat=2
http://site.ru/view?nopage=1&cat=2
```

получаем

```
http://site.ru/view?cat=2 
http://site.ru/view 
http://site.ru/view?cat=2 
http://site.ru/view?nopage=1&cat=2
```

Comment: Что-то мне подсказывает, что использовать `url_parse` а потом собирать куски в URL проще. Но все равно +1 ;)

Comment: @DmitriySimushev, использование функций по назначению не наш метод ;)